# Mapping decibel range to linear audible intervals

Tags: gui, sound, music, sound-effects

I am working in an engine that encodes sound as decibels (dB). Let's assume the decibel range of human hearing is -60dB to 0dB.

Audibility is not linear across this range.

So my question is...

**How does one map a decibel range to a set of numbers (for example, 1-10), such that each number corresponds to (roughly) one linear step up in audibility?**

Comment: I have updated my answer. I hope it helps.

Comment: Are you asking simply for a mathematical formula to convert a number from (1, 10) to (-60, 0)?

Comment: @TomTsagk, no. That would help if audibility was linear across (-60, 0) dB, but it is not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We use `dBvalue = 20 * log10( volumeAsPercent )` where `volumeAsPercent` is in the range of [0.001 .. 1]. `dbValue` will be in the range of [-60 .. 0].

(That's a bit annoying because the actual engine - OpenAL - uses 0..1 for its *gain*, so we have to convert that back using `volumeAsPercent = 2^(dBvalue/6)`. It will not exactly give the same result as the input but will give an approximation to `volumeAsPercent = 10^(dBvalue/20)` which is close enough (I don't know why we use that formula, and we can't change it at this point).)

I'm not a sound engineer, I don't play music and I don't have a sound studio to test this, but testing this formula with increments of 10%, seems to give a nice progression in making the sound louder (from completely muted at 0, up to what is in the original wav file at 1).

[Here are the plotted curves.](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/jogixtfuc4)